# Weka cross validation wrong results

Tags: weka, test-data, cross-validation

I am classifying 5 minutes of EEG data of 4 classes using a Bayesian Network.

When applying cross validation I get 100% correct results whereas when I use training and supplied testing data (the first 3.7 minutes for training, 1.3 minutes for testing) in a separate file I get really low results (30%).

I am new to Weka and do not know how this is possible. Any help would be highly appreciated :)

Comment: Do you do crossvalidation using your training *and* your test data or only with one of them?

Comment: I have the whole dataset loaded in weka, 300 instances, and I choose the cross validation option.So as far as I understand it should divide this whole dataset to the number of folds specified and each time hold out a part for testing.
To elaborate more I got to experiment around more and discovered that when I use the "Randomize" filter and put the data in a random order then split into training and test sets I also get results close to 100%. Cross validation automatically randomizes. without randomizing(first 3.3 mins training, 1.7 testin in separate file) i get 40% and lower.